# SQLite3 - memory usage gradually increases until all available memory are consumed

Tags: c++, linux, memory, sqlite

I am experiencing a memory usage issue while running a simple single-threaded C++ program for long time (say over night). The program uses SQLite3 API to open a data base and writes some data in it within a loop.I am running the program on two different machines: a desktop Ubuntu Linux and an ARM based embedded device running a custom built Linux.
In both cases I am getting the same results: Memory is consumed gradually and not released while application is running. I am checking memory usage using a simple bash script running in background:

```
while true;
do free -m;
sleep 2;
done
```

It should be noted that I am also monitoring memory usage using SQLite provided API:

```
sqlite3_memory_used()
```

The API reports a fairly stable amount of used memory but the "free -m" report is different and increases gradually.

The SQLite source code is compiled with the following flags:

```
SQLITE_DEFAULT_TEMP_CACHE_SIZE=3
SQLITE_DEFAULT_WAL_AUTOCHECKPOINT=2
SQLITE_MAX_MMAP_SIZE=2048
SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMSYS5
SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=3
SQLITE_DEFAULT_AUTOVACUUM=1
SQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=512
```

Please note that at this stage I am not concerned about speed but my main concern is memory usage so I set parameters in such a way that minimum data is cached in memory and get them pushed to the disk as soon as possible.

I also use "PRAGMA shrink_memory" in each iteration.

To minimise dynamic memory allocation I have also provided static arrays for the following memory types:

```
SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP
SQLITE_CONFIG_SCRATCH
SQLITE_CONFIG_PAGECACHE
```

And the code snippet which writes to database looks like this:

```
char SQL_Statement[100]={0};
char *ErrMsg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    sprintf(SQL_Statement, "INSERT INTO PointValue (TimeStamp, BlockId, PointId, Value) VALUES (%f, %d, %d, %d);",TimeStamp_ ,BlockId_, PointId_, Value_ );
    check =  sqlite3_exec(MyDB, SQL_Statement, callback, (void*)data, &ErrMsg); 
    sqlite3_free(ErrMsg);
}
```

Comment: `char SQL_Statement[100]={0};`  Looking at that `sprintf`, you are balancing on a knife's edge if you're declaring an array of only 100 characters.  I wouldn't be surprised if you're creating a memory overwrite by declaring such a small ampunt.

Comment: That should be "small amount".

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie for your comment. I checked size of the produced string and confirmed that it is below 100 (it is 85 characters). All the parameters are fixed values and not growing.

Comment: I don't suppose you can turn Valgrind loose on this overnight with debuggable source for sqlite? I think it would be revealing. And do you experience similar characteristics *off* that ARM rig?

Comment: The evidence shows that the memory is not used by SQLite. Furthermore, is that memory consumed by this process or by file caches?

Comment: Thanks @CL - You are right. The memory is consumed by linux page cache which is fine because Linux hopefully takes care of it and releases unnecessary pages when another application need more memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers and comments. 
It is confirmed that The memory is consumed by linux page cache which is fine because Linux hopefully takes care of it and releases unnecessary pages when another application need more memory. 
just using a simple command:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of **sqlite3_exec** is only set when an error ocurred in this case is initialized calling sqlite3_malloc, and need to be freed, but when no error ocurred is set to NULL, maybe is a problem calling sqlite3_free, with a NULL variable. Try adding a condition:

```
if (ErrMsg != nullptr) // if C++11 or NULL o 0 if C++98
    sqlite3_free(ErrMsg);
```

Look url: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html
As Sqlite3 documentation state, the memory passed to the callback no need any free call, all would be automatically free and invalid to use after sqlite3_step() witch is called internally in sqlite3_exec, because of this, if you need to save the value in the callback for latter use, you need you make a copy of it, the pointer would became invalid in the next callback call or the code executed after.

Comment: Thanks @NetVipeC for your answer. I've applied your suggestion in my code but unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Other recommendation would be using prepared statements, the initialization and possibly allocation of **SQL_Statement** in every pass of the loop could be exhausting, and the 100 char limit impose a limit in the data inserted that could represent a problem in the future. The pseudo code would be: `1-Prepare Statement one time. 2-Loop through data. 3-Bind Columns with data. 4-Step statement. 5-Reset Statement`

Comment: @NetVipeC if the prototype of `sqlite3_exec`'s third parameter is `int selectCB(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);`, must `argv ` and `azColName` be `free` ?